# How to work around geoCoder error:503

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, mkreversegeocoder

I have tried so many solutions but nothing seems to work for me. Approximately one out of every 4 times i get

```
/SourceCache/ProtocolBuffer_Sim/ProtocolBuffer-51.2/Runtime/PBRequester.m:684 server returned error: 503
```

I have declared the geocoder at the class level and added a retain property (just like in apple's CurrentAddress sample code) and released in **dealloc** method.

During instantiation i have added it to the autorelease pool as shown below

```
self.reverseGeocoder =[[[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:newLocation.coordinate]autorelease];
reverseGeocoder.delegate=self;
[reverseGeocoder start];
```

This was the suggestions i got from other solutions. Apparently nothing seems to work for me.

Am i doing something wrong? I am beginning to wonder if there a solution at all? :(

Thanks in advance

Comment: 503 is a standard http status code. See here http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E503.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to go through google map api

this may help you 
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to go for google api for map.

You need to run java/Script on UiWebView by your custom function...